# how to make a makemigrations with django 2.1

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, database-migration, django-2.1

I try to make a makemigrations but I always have the same error :

```
File "/Users/my-user/Personal-Project/projet/env/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/funcy/colls.py", line 87, in join
result.update(d)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is 
required
```

I don't understand. My model looks like :

```
class Territory(models.Model):
"""
Represent a territory (area/city) where the service is available.
"""

class Meta:
    verbose_name = _("Territory")
    verbose_name_plural = _("Territories")
    ordering = ["name"]

name = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name=_("Territory name"), unique=True, db_index=True)
identifier = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name=_("Territory key"), unique=True)
default_timezone = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name=_("Default timezone"))
default_currency = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name=_("Default currency"))

def __unicode__(self):
    return "Territory %s %s" % (self.identifier, self.name)

@classmethod
def get_territory_by_key(cls, territory_key):
    """ Return the territory associated to the given key """
    try:
        return cls.objects.get(identifier=territory_key)
    except cls.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

So if someone has an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly error is because you are using funcy.merge() somewhere in your code , and passing some wrong parameter in it.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in my settings file, I put some wrong parameters for cacheops